# UWP update Button content in UIThread

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I have a button that does a backgroud task (it searches lyrics from the Internet for all music files). And it updates the button content by incrementing the counter as it fetches the lyrics.

```
    private async void AddLyrics_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            string format = Helper.LocalizeMessage("PostParenthesis");
            HyperlinkButton button = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
            int count = MusicLibraryPage.AllSongs.Count;
            for (searchLyricsCounter = 1; searchLyricsCounter < count + 1; searchLyricsCounter++)
            {
                Music music = MusicLibraryPage.AllSongs[searchLyricsCounter - 1];
                string lyrics = await music.GetLyricsAsync();
                //if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lyrics))
                //{
                //    lyrics = await Controls.MusicLyricsControl.SearchLyrics(music);
                //    await music.SaveLyricsAsync(lyrics);
                //}
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(searchLyricsCounter);
                button.Content = string.Format(format, addLyricsContent, searchLyricsCounter + "/" + count);
            }
            searchLyricsCounter = 0;
            button.Content = Helper.Localize("AddLyrics");
            Helper.ShowNotification("SearchLyricsDone");
        });
    }
```

The button is located in a page (SettingsPage) of a Frame in the MainPage. After I switch to another page  and change back to SettingsPage, the button stops updating the content, although the thread is still running.

How can I keep the button content updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the page on cache. Set NavigationCacheMode property to Enabled or Required.

On XAML.

```
<Page NavigationCacheMode="Enabled">

</Page>
```

Or in Code-Behind

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
{
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Click event already runs on UI Thread

```
private async void AddLyrics_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    HyperlinkButton button = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
    button.IsEnabled = false; // avoid duplicate clicks
    try
    {
        string format = Helper.LocalizeMessage("PostParenthesis");
        int count = MusicLibraryPage.AllSongs.Count;
        int searchLyricsCounter = 1;
        foreach(Music music in MusicLibraryPage.AllSongs)
        {
            string lyrics = await music.GetLyricsAsync();        
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(searchLyricsCounter);
            button.Content = string.Format(format, addLyricsContent, searchLyricsCounter + "/" + count);
        }        
        button.Content = Helper.Localize("AddLyrics");
        Helper.ShowNotification("SearchLyricsDone");
    }
    finally
    {
        button.IsEnabled = true; // Can click now
    }
}
```

[Read more about NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-18362)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `NavigationCacheMode` to `Enabled`.